# How can I get an owner draw tree?

Tags: treeview, kendo-ui

How can I get an owner draw tree? One where I draw each node in the tree?

What I need is to have a line of text that has up to 3 hyperlinks in it. Each hyperlink needs to fire an event where I can then pop up a menu or window that is based on the node clicked and which of the 3 links was clicked.

I would also like to have a bitmap at the end that's a (x) type close button. This can be just the text [X] if a bitmap is impossible.

How can this be done? Or should I ask, can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `templates` for defining how each node of your tree needs to look like, you can define any possible `HTML` and `JavaScript`.

Example: Define a node where we show each node `text` and three HTML anchors (`a`). Then, we bind a `click` event to each of the links as follow:

Template definition

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    <div class="ob-item">
        <div>#: item.text #</div>
        This is <a class='link1' href='\#'>Link 1</a>
        and this is <a class='link2' href='\#'>Link 2</a>
        and finally <a class='link3' href='\#'>Link 3</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Define `TreeView`:

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
    dataSource: [
        ...
    ]
});
```

Bind events:

```
$(document).on("click", ".link1", function (e) {
    treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var node = $(this).closest(".k-item");
    var item = treeview.dataItem(node);
    alert("Clicked on link1 of node with id: " + item.id + " and text: " + item.text);
});
$(document).on("click", ".link2", function (e) {
    treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var node = $(this).closest(".k-item");
    var item = treeview.dataItem(node);
    alert("Clicked on link2 of node with id: " + item.id + " and text: " + item.text);
});
$(document).on("click", ".link3", function (e) {
    treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var node = $(this).closest(".k-item");
    var item = treeview.dataItem(node);
    alert("Clicked on link3 of node with id: " + item.id + " and text: " + item.text);
});
```

A JSFiddle showing it in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hv4FV/1

Comment: If you want to see it with a KendoUI styled close button http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hv4FV/5/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via templates. Check this example: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/templates.html

Comment: That's nice for the bitmap. Is there a way to have 3 distinct clickable sections in the node? Can I do that by just breaking out the text with 3 <a href=... and have each using a distinct OnClick?

Comment: Yes. Adding three hypelinks with onclick attribute set is the way to go.